# Object showing back at frame 1

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hi I'm new to flash and as3 and have very basic knowledge with as3, I'm trying to create a simple drag and drop games, my goal the games need to be work as a stack layering objects like making a hamburger ( sorry I don't know how to say this but as below pictures )

[image]

My Timeline

[image]

My actions for frame 1

```
 stop();

bantenbiakaon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bantenbiakaonquiz);

function bantenbiakaonquiz ( event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(2);

}
```

Actions at frame 2

```
stop();
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;



sidi.buttonMode = true;
sidi.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
sidi.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);         



function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.startDrag();
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    objectoriginalX = event.target.x;
    objectoriginalY = event.target.y;
}

function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
    var matchingTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
    var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
    if(event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget)
    {
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
        event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
            gotoAndStop(3);


    }
    else
    {
        event.target.x = objectoriginalX;
        event.target.y = objectoriginalY;
    }
}
```

Actions at frame 3 will drag and drop to target and then open frame 4

Actions at frame 4 a Symbol MouseEvent gotoAndPlay(1); to frame 1

My problem when all object has been put into the target when the Symbol Button click back to frame 1, the object still appear. How actually to fix my problem.

Problem screenshot at frame 1

[image]

Comment: Mixing timelines and script is a bad practice - and you already know why. As soon as you do **event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);** Flash forgets it is a timeline object and does not destroy it as you go to frame where it (as you planned) doesn't exist. I advise to put these 4 objects and drag-n-drop scripts into separate container (MovieClip), so Flash will destroy the whole container (regardless you messed with its inner content) when you're back to frame 1.

Comment: Thank you Organis, I will try your suggestions